# Adding the same entity object to SQL server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, frameworks

Im trying to add the same object to a table using a for loop as a job entity may be required more than once. I tried it this way first but it only saves one record.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < required; i++)
                {
                    _Context.Jobs.AddObject(n);
                }
```

Then I tried this way thinking entity framework might not see the objects as being different.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < required; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        Job additionalJob = new Job();
                        additionalJob = n;
                        _salesContext.Jobs.AddObject(additionalJob);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _Context.Jobs.AddObject(n);
                    }
                }
```

The database only saves on record. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are reference types. What ever n is you are setting the additionalJob to it, which is exactly the same thing. Classes use pointers to a space in memory so all you are doing is making two pointers. When you add the record EF is just adding the same data.

Instead of setting to n, copy the properties over from n.

ie,

```
additionaljob.Name = n.Name;
```

or

```
var additonalJob = new Job() { Name = n.Name };
```

Comment: Yeah I thought this is what I would have to do, I was just hoping now to have to do that as there is quite a few properties in the job entity.

Ill give this a go now and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I've had problems like this, I created a helper function that loops through the properties of the class and copies them over to a destination class. That would be really easy to do and would save a lot of typing and be more maintainable.

Comment: Thats a great idea! Also your answer worked perfectly, i'll mark it as the answer now.

Thanks for your help.